# How do I add roles with the least possible code in ASP.Net MVC OWIN without Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, owin

I've used the last couple of days searching Google & here on Stack, but cant seem to find a suitable solution for my problem.

I'm currently developing a web application using ASP.NET following the MVC pattern & currently using mySQL as DB. I have followed this article briefly to implement user login features:
http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1. All users have an attribute which defines their role.

My next step is to limit all Admin features in my AdminController to Admin only user(s). But it seems that all solutions rely on using the "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" package. I do however not use Entity at all, why? Because I like to be in control of my queries & like to write them my self so Entity is not the answer here, I use ADO.net.

**My question:** How do I implement simple user roles so that I can use the "[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]" attribute on my controller, without using the Entity framework and only working with OWIN.

Comment: *http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1* More or less shows this: when doing `new ClaimsIdentity` add a `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "xxx")`

Comment: Yeah I have seen that article, but having sensibel data like admin user role in cookies is not the smartest thing to do, since it can be forged quite easily. Am I right? Also how do I go from that so that the [authorize] attribute understands it ? :-)

Comment: If you inspect the cookie you will probably find it to be encrypted...

Comment: Yes I know that they are encrypted. But people still seem to think that it's bad practice. However I will try it thanks